# Show selected name instead of ID in rails index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm a newbie at rails and I'm trying as best as I can follow tutorials that abound the web.  So I have three tables.

```
  class CreateAuthors <
     ActiveRecord::Migration   def self.up
         create_table :authors do |t|
           t.string :name
           t.string :email

           t.timestamps
         end

       end

       def self.down
         drop_table :authors end end


 class CreateTopics <
 ActiveRecord::Migration   def self.up
     create_table :topics do |t|
       t.string :category

       t.timestamps
     end   end

   def self.down
     drop_table :topics 
   end
end
```

Now the Articles reference the author_id and topic_id

```
class CreateArticles <
 ActiveRecord::Migration   def self.up
     create_table :articles do |t|
       t.string :title
       t.integer :author_id
       t.integer :topic_id
       t.text :content
       t.integer :status

       t.timestamps
     end   end

   def self.down
     drop_table :articles   end end
```

Now for the new.html.erb and edit.html.erb I found out how to use collection_select to get the records from the topics and authors.

```
<% form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :author_id %><br />
    <%= @authors =Author.find(:all, :order => 'name')
    collection_select(:article,:author_id, @authors,:id,:name) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :topic_id %><br />
    <%= @topics = Topic.find(:all, :order => 'category') 
        collection_select(:article,:topic_id, @topics,:id,:category) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :status %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :status %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Now for my view how do I return the names in the index and show view and not the id?

```
<td><%=h article.topic_id %></td>
    <td><%=h article.title %></td>
    <td><%=h article.author_id %></td>
    <td><%=h article.status %></td>
```

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
@authors =Author.find(:all, :order => 'name')
```

and this:

```
@topics = Topic.find(:all, :order => 'category')
```

should be in your controller in corresponding actions (`new` and `edit`).

Your models should look like this:

```
# Article model
belongs_to :author
belogns_to :topic

# Author model
has_many :articles

# Topic model
has_many :articles
```

With this you can do what you want in this way:

```
<td><%=h @article.title %></td>
<td><%=h @article.author.name %></td>
<td><%=h @article.status %></td>
```

And any other variations: `@article.topic.category`, `@author.articles.first.topic` etc.

Comment: A better explanation. Removing my answer. Typo in your article model though.

Comment: @ghoppe yours answer was also good. Especialy when he will many times access `article.author.name` it would be better to load author into `@author` and use it.

Comment: I was able to get it to show the view and found the typo as well. Awesome and thanks again guys.

Comment: Well, if you feel that's the case, I'll undelete it. Heh.

Comment: No I think there would be others that will benefit from it as well. Cheers again

Answer (score 3):

This approach isn't quite the Ruby on Rails way of doing things, you're mixing controller logic into your View. You should have `@authors = Author.find(:all, :order => 'name')` etc. in your controller, not your View.

Similarly, in your Controller you would have:

```
@author = Author.find(@article.author_id);
```

And in your View you would show the author name:

```
<%=h @author.name %>
```

Comment: This looks really like the right approach to do things. Works perfectly.